# How can I determine the ABI version (and other details) of a compiled native module?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions, node-serialport

I am collaborating on a VSCode extension for which a native module (serialport)  is used.
in order to make the solution run stable on all platforms and over time as VScode changes electron versions, i would like to include the prebuild native modules.

it now appears that some (not all) of these precompiled modules are not the version they claim to be.

for testing / validation i would like to programmatically determine the ABI version, and if possible the runtime , platform ( darwin , linux , win32 ) and architecture for each of the native modules downloaded by install-prebuild

ie the following error is thrown when I try to load the module in electron 5.0.10 (ABI-70):

```
Uncaught Error: The module '\\?\C:\develop\NodeJS\electron-serialport\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\lib\binding\node-v70-win32-x64\bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 47. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 70. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

so its reporting ABI 47 while it was downloaded download by prebuild-install as ABI 70.
Note: storing electron-bindings in node-bindings locations to allow 'bindings' to detect ABI , platform and architecture

```
## npx prebuild-install 
Download prebuild native binding for runtime electron : 5.0.5, abi: 70, win32, x64
prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 5.3.0
prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ C:\Users\josverl\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\bde028-bindings-v2.0.8-electron-v70-win32-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install info found cached prebuild
prebuild-install info unpacking @ C:\Users\josverl\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\bde028-bindings-v2.0.8-electron-v70-win32-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install info unpack resolved to C:\develop\NodeJS\electron-serialport\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node
prebuild-install info install Successfully installed prebuilt binary!

Copy to : 
 -> C:\develop\NodeJS\electron-serialport\noded_modules\@serialport\bindings\lib\binding\node-v70-win32-x64\bindings.node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

landed on a decent but partial solution, as I have not been able to find an API or true  cross platform solution.

The closest I could get is by directly using [process.dlopen](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_dlopen_module_filename_flags) but that still only gives a success or throws an error.
the underlying [loader](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d3b10f66bd4943f7da9aa25415ea6900d7f48086/src/node_binding.cc#L485) does have the information `mp->nm_version`, but it is only reported though the error.

So the only way found thus far is to parse that error message. limitation is that this can only work on same platform and CPU architecture as the current runtime, but it is better than nothing at all.

The below will extract a native module's ABI version by catching the error message and extracting the ABI from that.

```
// try to determine the ABI version for a native module
const getNativeABI = (filename) => {
    var moduleVersion = 0
    try {
        var test = new Module(filename, null);
        process.dlopen(module, filename) //,os.constants.dlopen.RTLD_NOW);
        // if this works the node version is the same 
        moduleVersion = process.versions['modules']
        // but now we need to unload it :-( 
        return moduleVersion
    } catch (error) {
        var match
        var versionRegexp = /NODE_MODULE_VERSION (\d*)./gm
        var platformRegexp = /(is not a valid Win32 application|invalid ELF header|wrong ELF class)/g
        // check for ABI version mismatch 
            // Uncaught Error: The module '..\bindings.node'
            // was compiled against a different Node.js version using
            // NODE_MODULE_VERSION 47. This version of Node.js requires
            // NODE_MODULE_VERSION 70. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
        match = versionRegexp.exec(error.message)
        if (match != null){
            return match[1] // first version is that of the module 
        } 
        // not for valid on this win32 / linux 
        match = platformRegexp.exec(error.message)
        if (match != null){
            // todo: @linux : use error for elfclass to determine architecture :: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
            return 0 // can't validate cross platform
        } 
        // other error 
        console.debug( error.message)
    }
    return moduleVersion // just in case
}
```

you'll need to pass in an dummy Module structure.

```
/// dummy copy of  internal function
function Module(id, parent) {
    this.id = id;
    this.exports = {};
    this.parent = parent;
    // updateChildren(parent, this, false);
    this.filename = null;
    this.loaded = false;
    this.children = [];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`process.versions.modules` should get you the correct ABI for the given node or electron runtime.</strike>

Your own solution is the only way to do this without a addition native node module, and parsing/reading the `.node` file does not give you the information directly as string or int value **(Checked with an hex editor)**.

Possible reasons are:

- You should be sure that the install process of the module does not trigger the building of your native module eg: running `npm install` without `--ignore-scripts.`, since this uses your locally installed node version to rebuild any dependancy if the containing package has a custom install script.
- Your pre-build is beeing ignored by other install steps
- The package has uploaded the wrong `.node` files as prebuild.

Comment: well , no , that is not the issue at all.
for one , it would be presumptious to assume that any and all users of a piece of software have the ability to compile a native module from  c / c++ source.

Comment: install-prebuild  is meant to prevent to need to build for source, as that is done by the original authors ofelectron 5.0.10 (ABI-70): the module , and they are provided for download. 
but then the binaries that are delivered are expected to be the correct ABI version, and that does not seem to be the case.
alsoas specified this is on

Comment: and lastly , I want to get the ABI to a 'to be loaded module', not of the runtime

Comment: Okay, i really misunderstood your question there. But still your download has to be been overwritten after your manually installed your package otherwise you would not have loaded ABI 47.

Regarding your issue parsing the sting like you did in your own awnser is the only way to get this information without writing another native library or looking for the meta information by reading/parsing the node file, but I did not find a int or string containing the ABI version in the `.node` at first glance.

Comment: Also from what I see there is an issue with serialport https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/issues/1884 probably the cached `node` file contains the wrong build.

Comment: in other words : the assumption "still your download has to be been overwritten after your manually installed your package otherwise you would not have loaded ABI 47." has proved not to be correct.
Thanks for the other issue though , I had overlooked that but is is the same issue indeed.

Comment: This is tricky to spot indeed, at least it's a great example on why data (from any source) never should be trusted blindly :)